# Google-Drive related tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

EDIT: [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) is now a synonym for [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk), so we're part-way there.

Now - how about making [google-drive-realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-realtime-api) a synonym as well?

---

There are three tags on SO that imo cover the same topic, from a programming standpoint.

[google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) (3,307 questions), [google-drive-realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-realtime-api) (226) and [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) (115). We should keep [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk), and make the other two synonyms.

The info pages for the latter two reference the same product documentation, https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/. The primary source link for [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) is https://developers.google.com/drive/, which is a container for the other reference.

These other tags related to the Google Drive service should still remain, as they serve unique purposes within SO:

- [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) - general references to the service, often without specific API
- [google-drive-android-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-android-api) - specific API

Comment: So... how do I get attention for the requests I've submitted? Is there a holy quest that I must first complete? If so, I've got some coconuts, and I'm ready to go.

Comment: The realtime API is very definitely NOT a synonym for the Drive SDK. It is within the SDK, but it's a very specific AP dealing with operation transforms (collaborative data), and has a specific set of demands, oddities and techniques. 90% of people writing code that deals with the Drive SDK won't touch the realtime API at all, but for those of us that do... we need that tag.

Comment: I've just posted a [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321322/the-google-drive-realtime-api-tag-is-used-incorrectly-often-than-not) about re-naming it, which might possibly be a better solution to its overuse.

Comment: @Bhargav Err... status declined and completed?

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, the realtime API is different and shouldn't be merged along with the drive-sdk and drive-api, both of which were merged. (Partially done, Partially declined)