# The "google-drive-realtime-api" tag is used incorrectly more often than not

Tags: discussion, tags

To be clear: we need this tag, and I would hate to see it go away.

Perhaps because it starts with "google-drive", the "google-drive-realtime-api" tag (which concerns a very specific API within the Drive SDK) is often thrown in on questions that are completely unrelated to it. I've been removing these tags recently, but it's a pain, and makes the tag less useful overall.

Is there a process for changing the name of a tag, or a better way to reduce the number of times this happens?

Comment: The usage guidance should be updated to actually be a guide on how to use it, rather than just a description of what it is. It should specifically state not to use it for general Google Drive API questions, only for those concerning the realtime part.

Comment: Looks like there's a [tag:google-drive-sdk] tag already. Sounds like, as usual, people don't know what they're doing when it comes to tags. Thanks for helping to keep the place clean :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah, and it's a shame for them too, as usually google-drive-sdk is what they wanted, and they'd get the right kind of attention. I substitute that tag when it appears it would help.

Comment: @BSMP The tag description is really not bad, but you're right that it should actively *discourage* using it for regular Drive API questions.

Comment: You need to also specify what you need the new name to be, in your request.

Comment: @BhargavRao Google discontinued the service December 13th 2018, which a) screwed a bunch of people including me, and b) made this 3-year old problem somewhat moot.