# What tags could be applied to a question about using Google Drive to search for Google App Maker files?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

Few hours ago I posted the following question:

[How to search for App Maker files on Google Drive UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57749431/1595451)

Happily I got an answer very fast, but now I'm wondering if it's tagged properly.

- [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) is a synonym of [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api). The wiki of this tag says that questions about using the Google Drive UI should be posted on https://webapps.stackexchange.com. Usually I agree with this but I think that my question is on-topic on SO as the Google App Maker files are stored on Google Drive "automatically" (actually, besides of exporting whole app / modules App Maker files should be stored on Google Drive).
- I have been told that the question isn't really about [google-app-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-maker)

What tags could be applied to my question? Should a new tag be created? What about `google-drive-ui-for-programmers` :) ?

---

Related

- [Google-Drive related tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266532/1595451)

  This meta question from 2014 suggested to keep [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) as an independent tag.